# Prevent menu from loading in a page template

Tags: menus, pages, page-template, filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove navigation from header in custom page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76341/remove-navigation-from-header-in-custom-page-template)

Is there some way to remove `wp_nav_menu` in a page template? I can't find anything related to page templates other than redirect default theme files etc.

I know that just placing the `header.php` content in the page template will do the trick but this seems a awkward hack.

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your theme, you have at least a few options.  You could 1. hide it with CSS.

```
.your-page-template-php #your-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Or 2. you could create a custom header file.  For example, duplicated header.php to header-nomenu.php.  And in your new file delete the menu.  And then in your page template instead of calling

```
get_header();
```

you'd call

```
get_header('nomenu');
```

---

**EDIT**

Upon further review there *is* a filter inside the `wp_nav_menu` function.  Conditional logic will probably work as long as you haven't messed around with the query object and forgot to reset it.

```
function wpa76334_filter_nav_menu($menu, $args){
    if( is_page_template('your-template.php')) $menu = null;
    return $menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','wpa76334_filter_nav_menu', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm hidding with css :S

Comment: The answer I've just provided here should work: [Similar Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76343/5339).

Comment: Good answer @JeremyJared.  That would work perfectly in a custom theme or anywhere else you are cool with editing header.php.  Looks like this question is a duplicate then.

Comment: I thought there is some filter to prevent functions in template pages :( that's ok.

Comment: You were right actually.  There is a filter in `wp_nav_menu`.  Let me edit my answer.