# Remove navigation from header in custom page template

Tags: menus, templates, page-template

I'm building a landing page and want to remove the navigation menu from the page. The navigation menu is in header.php which is of course in the page template. Is there a WordPress function I can use to remove the navigation menu from this specific page? I know I could do it with jQuery and do display:none for the nav menu but i'd like to do it server side before the page loads.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a conditional tag:

Codex References:

[Function Reference (is_page)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

[Function Reference (Conditional Tags)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

You can specify the landing page by Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug.

Here is an example:

```
<?php if ( !is_page( 'landing-page' ) ) { 
  wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'show_home' => 'Home', 
    'container' => 'false', 
    'theme_location' => 'main') 
    ); 
  }
  endif;
  ?>
```

It excludes the page (in this case the page with the slug "landing-page") by placing the **`!`** in front of `is_page`

No need for javascript, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered on a [duplicate question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/prevent-menu-from-loading-in-a-page-template/), but another solution is to filter `wp_nav_menu`.

Conditional logic will probably work as long as you haven't messed around with the query object and forgot to reset it.

```
function wpa76334_filter_nav_menu($menu, $args){
    if( is_page_template('your-template.php')) $menu = null; //use your own conditions
    return $menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','wpa76334_filter_nav_menu', 10, 2);
```